# Sitecore WebForms for Marketers - find out all references

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

Is there any way in Sitecore to examine form instances (Web Forms for Marketers) under the `Sitecore\System\Web Forms for Marketers` node and see all places where each form is referenced?  I've tried selecting a form, then selecting the `Navigate` and `Links` from the main menu in the Sitecore content editor, but this doesn't seem to show any references.  If this is not possible can anyone explain *why* references to forms work in a different way to other things in Sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references to the form are inside the redenerrings field in the form interpreter parameters. 
My guess is the developers of the forms module don't add the reference to the link database when the form Interpreter is added.

If you want to find links to a form you'll need to create an admin page that goes through all the items in the tree and checks whether the renderings fields contains the forms id.